# How to Bind entire datagrid to view MVVM following the MVVM pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I want to dynamically display data in form a of a table. The control I chose for different reasons is a `DataGrid`. That solution worked to a certain point, but when I needed to dyanmically alter which properties I wanted to display in the datagrid I encountered problems. When I bind its `ItemsSource` directly to an observable it shows all properties in the specific object, which I dont want. I want to Create a datagrid programatically and push it into the view somehow. Is that even possible?

I've been looking now for a long time but I can't seem to find a good solution. It's also important that the solution follows the MVVM-pattern.

```
public class MyViewModel 
{
    public Datagrid dataGrid = null;
    public MyObject gridObject = null;

    public MyViewModel () 
    {
           gridObject = new MyObject();
           dataGrid = CreateDataGrid(gridObject);
    }

    private Datagrid CreateDataGrid(object objectName) {}
}
```

After this I want to bind the grid to the XAML. Is it possible or is there a better way of doing this, rather then a `DataGrid`? I want the functionality built into the datagrid like moving columns, mark specific rows etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't create a `DataGrid` in a view model. This is no MVVM. You create it in the view.

If you don't want the `DataGrid` to autogenerate the columns for you, you should set its `AutoGenerateColumns` property to `false`.

You could then define the columns you want yourself, either in the XAML markup:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="..." Binding="{Binding Property}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Or programmatically:

```
dataGrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn() { Header = "header...", Binding = new Binding("Property") });
```

The view model should return an `IEnumerable<T>` from a public property that the `DataGrid` in the view binds to:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModelCollection}" ...
```

Make sure that you set the `DataContext` of the view to an instance of the view model for the binding to work:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new ViewModel();
}
```

Comment: Yeah but the problem is I can't access the dataGrid from the viewModel.. the x:Name is only reachable from the View.Xaml.cs and not the viewmodel.

Comment: You shouldn't access it from the view model. Didn't you read my answer. Accessing a DataGrid from a view model breaks the MVVM pattern and all what it's about. You create the columns in the view.

Comment: Oh ok... I must have misunderstood the  whole thing then.. From my "experience" I have always heard that I shouldn't do anything in the view.xaml.cs.. and the true "MVVM-style" is doing it in the viewmodel. Thanks alot for your reply, mm8!

Comment: @Tjulu: You should only do purely view-related things in the view. Creating controls is certainly view-related.

Comment: Ah, ok :) Alot of time has been thrown away because of that misunderstanding, haha! Thanks alot! I knew I could do the thing you said, but I didn't want to because I thought  it was the "wrong way" to do it.